# Frictionless Braking System for 2 wheeler using electromagnet

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, design, automotive-engineering

I'm developing a **Frictionless Braking System for 2 wheeler using electromagnet**. My questions were

1. How can we **overcome the problem of braking at Low speeds**. This type of braking tends to fail.
2. How can I **solve the problem of Emergency Braking without deviation in path** (For Example: If my motorcycle is travelling at a speed of 50kmph with a load of 120 kg and if there is an obstacle, how do I provide leverage to this brake)
3. How do I **mount my Electromagnets onto the brake callipe**r and **what type of electromagnets** should I use?(looking for specifications of electromagnets)
4. How do I **calculate Braking Torque, Force at the front and back wheels of the 2-wheeler, efficiency and other important parameters**? (Looking for formulas or Calculated examples)

I had tried to use a relay/ SMPS for the point 2 stated above.
I am using an Aluminium T6 6061 plate of 3mm thickness and 35 cm diameter.

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Have you checked out eddy current braking systems? lots of info around.

Comment: Cross posted here, and they suggested the Physics stack: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/530322/152903